# Java - Check if other programs read a file?

Tags: java, io, read-write

Can I somehow check if another program reads a specified file?

I want my program to monitor a file, and whenever it is accessed by another program, it should run some code. Is this possible?

Comment: You can log it. If that's what you are looking for.

Comment: this is going to be some low level OS code, it's not going to be possible in the Java API's. For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify

Comment: Whenever another program accesses a sound file, I want to run some code in Java. Can I check for this? EDIT: Ah, that's too bad.

Comment: Depending on the OS, but something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify

Comment: The API has WatchService for modifications (and I don't think access dates counts), but as @enl8enmentnow said I think it gets a bit lower if you want to monitor access since you'd need to monitor file descriptors or similar things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some people have mentionned, Java new IO offers you to watch a directory/files for some activities :

- ENTRY_CREATE – A directory entry is created.
- ENTRY_DELETE – A directory entry is deleted.
- ENTRY_MODIFY – A directory entry is modified.
- OVERFLOW – Indicates that events might have been lost or discarded. You do not have to register for the OVERFLOW event to receive it.

However, as you can see, it does not allow you to detect if the file has been accessed. If really you want to do that, you will have to write some native code.

On windows, you can list who access a file using [`Handle`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx). I believe you could call this command from a java program (let say each couple of minutes) then from the output detect if the file is used.

I'm pretty sure there is alternative for other OS.

Answer (score 1):

BasicFileAttributes interface offers last access time. But it wont be able to tell you which program accessed it. As mentioned by others WatchService will also do the same but what you want to do can be achieved via logging from those programs and then check those logs for determining what to do next.

Comment: It doesn't matter which program, since there's only one program that will be accessing the file. I will look into this, thanks.